# Can't see Note type custom field in reports

Tags: 4.6.8

After setting up a custom data set "Member Details", I later added a new text area field called "Notes" to the set. My problem is that I find no way to get any membership report to show the Notes field. It isn't in the checkbox list of columns. I know the Notes field could potentially be a lot of text, but I don't care too much what it does to the report table. We have very short notes.

To see the Notes fields I must generate a report, click a contact, then click the Memberships tab, then click the View link on the right. So it's sort of cumbersome. I would like to be able to view a lot of notes at once in a report table format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you confirmed that your notes field is searchable?  If it is, then the next step would be to check whether there are any ACLs working on that particular custom data set that might be restricting access.

Hope this helps,
Lesley

Comment: I didn't know that searchable affects column choices. That fixed it.